# Cumulative Normal Distribution function in objective C

Tags: iphone, statistics

Anyone know of a good implementation of this whose license is compatible with non-free iPhone apps?

As suggested in this question, Boost looks absolutely wonderful.  But as best I can tell, it is only available in C++.

[Cumulative Normal Distribution Function in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328258/cumulative-normal-distribution-function-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need for anything fancy.  Any platform with a good C99 math library (like the iphone) already has everything you need -- specifically the `erfc` function, which is a slight variant:

```
#import <math.h>

double cumulativeNormal(double x) {
    return 0.5 * erfc(-x * M_SQRT1_2);
}
```

Note this is for the standard normal distribution (i.e. mean = 0, variance = 1), you'll need to use the appropriate scaling -- so for some mean and variance, it will be:

```
return 0.5 * erfc(((mean - x)/sqrt(variance)) * M_SQRT1_2);
```

If you don't need double precision, change the doubles to floats, use the `erfcf` function, and change the literals to single-precision literals.

Remember, Objective-C is an extremely light extension to C.  Every C function is an Objective-C function, with no wrapping or other shenanigans required.

Answer (score 2):

So you specifically want an objective-c solution, correct? Because, just in case you were not already aware, you can use [C++ libraries within your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577838/how-to-build-boost-libraries-for-iphone).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, I wish I could accept both answers, as both are great.

Comment: No worries. Stephen provided an original answer, I just linked to another question that might have helped you :)