# Normal Distribution Functions

Tags: c

Is this the correct way to write the normal distribution function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution  or should I be using the pow function?   I am really confused so help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
double u,s, N, x1,math1, math2, math3,n, v, x;

printf("Enter Mean: ");
scanf("%lf", &u);
printf("Enter Standard Deviation: ");
scanf("%lf", &s);
printf("Enter Number Of Inputs: ");
scanf("%lf", &N);

    for (v=1; v<=N; v++)
    {
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    n=(-1/2);
    printf("f(x)= ");
    math1 =1/(s*sqrt(2*M_PI));
    math2= (x-u)/s * (x-u)/s;
    math3= M_E * exp(n);
    x1 = math1 * exp(math3)*exp(math2);
    printf("%lf  \n", x1);
    }
system("Pause");
 }
```

Comment: Ideally you should mix input and output from the user in the same function.

Comment: Quite close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328258/cumulative-normal-distribution-function-in-c-c - there's even some discussion in the comments as to why you shouldn't use `pow()`.

Comment: `-1/2` - this doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's too hard to read your code, but I can tell it's wrong.  Here is a short version:

```
double twopi = 8.0 * atan(1.0); // preferable to using M_PI
double x = ..., sigma = ..., mu = ...;
double y = (1.0 / (sigma * sqrt(twopi))) *
    exp(-(x - mu)*(x - mu) / (2.0 * sigma * sigma));
```

Notice how I translate the mathematical formula directly to an expression in C... this makes it easy to verify that the code is correct.  It's a bit harder when you use a bunch of temporary variables `math1`, `math2`, `math3`...

Remember: `exp()` is the same thing as its counterpart in mathematics, `exp`.  So `exp(x)` is e<sup>x</sup>.  Once you realize this, you will see the errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! I think you are missing a end ')' for the very first one before '(1.0'