# Cumulative Normal Distribution Function in C/C++ with parameters

Tags: c++, matlab, cdf

I want to implement equivalent of matlab normcdf function in C++, I have already found this useful post: [Cumulative Normal Distribution Function in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328258/cumulative-normal-distribution-function-in-c-c) pointing to this implementation http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_phi.html. But I want it with optional mu and sigma parameters as in matlab.

Is it ok, when I change this:

```
x = fabs(x)/sqrt(2.0);
```

to:

```
x = fabs(x - mu)/sqrt(2.0 * sigma * sigma);
```

or I am supposed to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out - you want to save the sign of `x-mu`, not just of `x`:

```
int sign = 1;
if (x < mu)
    sign = -1;
x = fabs(x-mu)/sqrt(2.0*sigma*sigma);
```

Otherwise your scaling is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead add

```
x = (x-mu)/fabs(sigma);
```

as the first line of the function for the correct result without changing the sign check. Ideally you should throw an exception for `sigma<=0.0` rather than use `fabs` here.

On an unrelated note, the implementation that you've linked to is actually a single precision approximation just having had `float` replaced with `double` (hence the max error being a *whopping* 7e-8 ;-).
If you're comfortable translating from VB, West gives an implementation of Hart's *much* more accurate approximation in figure 2 of http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/090721_west.pdf.
Unfortunately, as a PDF, you can't copy and paste all the magic numbers so you'll have to be *very* careful when checking that you've copied them correctly!